# How to setup PhpSpreadsheet in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpspreadsheet

I have installed PhpSpreadsheet via composer now need to know the service provider to enter in app.php to use it in my controller.

Comment: PhpSpreadsheet is a PHP library not necessary built for just Laravel. You can read their documentation on how to use it here: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ If you wish to create a service provider out of it you can read about that there: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container. You'll have to make your own.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest you use this wrapper around PhpSpreadSheet for Laravel:
https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

But you can use PhpSpreadSheet as it is, just as the documentation points out: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#welcome-to-phpspreadsheets-documentation

For using a service provider for this PHP library, you'd need to create it by yourself

And of course, try to do first some research by yourself.